# iFrame embedded on page is not clickable in any

Tags: html, css, iframe, hover, click

I have a page https://www.visitmontaione.com/wp4/en/montaione-tuscany-italy/services/ where is embedded an iframe, but it is not clickable.

I don't understand why. Maybe there is some script that block any possibility to click on the element.

Someone can help me? Many thanks

Filippo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This frame has the rule `pointer-events: none` - this prohibits any actions with the selector. You need to assign an `unset` parameter for this rule, like this - `pointer-events: unset`.

With a howl css (style.css) find a reference to the `iframe` tag (246 lines), and add `pointer-events: unset!important`. You should get like this:

```
iframe {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;

    pointer-events: unset!important; /*add this it*/
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

an option is to wrap the iframe with a clickable element

u can instead put the iframe inside the button

```
 <button><iframe></iframe></button>
    
    button {
      display : block; /* or inline-block */
    }
    button iframe {
      pointer-events : none;
      position: relative;
      z-index : 0;
    }
```